# Append text to product title on multiple pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to append text to WooCommerce product title in the order meta - if products has a specific tag. I'm working from

- "[Append text to product title if product has product-tag on cart in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246609/11987538)"
- "[Display custom payment field in Woocommerce Admin, Orders and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889393/11987538)"

This is what I have so fare:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_udstilling_below_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function add_udstilling_below_cart_item_name( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {;

    $new_total_rows = [];

    foreach($total_rows as $key => $total ){
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;


        }
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243482/woocommerce-filter-product-title-if-product-has-product-tag/60246609#60246609) and this new question, I assume that you would like to see the product title adjusted 'everywhere'.

> IMPORTANT!! You should definitely read the following post to
>   understand that this is a general adjustment, so that you ultimately
>   no longer need the code from your previous post / question
>
> [Changing WooCommerce cart item names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994359/changing-woocommerce-cart-item-names/44994871#44994871)

In other words, you can start using the code below to see the adjustment in the following places

- Order-receive (Thank you) page,
- email notifications
- My Account Orders> Single order details
- Cart & Checkout and Backend Order edit pages.

**Now you have change the names everywhere except on Shop archives and product pages…**

```php
function add_udstilling_order_item_name( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        if( method_exists( $product, 'set_name' ) && has_term( 'udstillingsmodel', 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) {
            $product->set_name( $product->get_name() . '(test)' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_udstilling_order_item_name', 10, 1 );
```