# How do I hardcode automatic bundle deals? ie 4 for 30

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For our Woocommerce project, we are selling a specific product for say $8 but when four are added to the cart, we then want it to either add a $2 discount.

This would happen an infinite number of times: ie 4, 8, 12 etc

This needs to be hardcoded and NOT use coupons; capable developer, and I will post finished solution, but I just can't find where to necessarily start.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check at checkout if the quantity mod 4 is 0 then you  can add the discount.

Comment: Thats exactly my thinking, but can you please link to the specific woo hook or functionality? It's the execution priority and function/method I'm struggling to find. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what Woocommerce framework you are using, but it's most likely to find the function that sums all the prices and to modify it a bit. Good luck!

Comment: can you get started with this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357546/11987538

Comment: I can, thank you! I'll move this to the answer.

Comment: if my answer can help you, you can always upvote it (on the url I shared). 
Maybe afterwards you can post the solution to your own question here to help other visitors (the modified code). Regards

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow.com/a/60357546/11987538

Answers this query (and adds possibilities for variation by tags)